# Updating MySQL Innodb Index Statistics

Tags: mysql, database

We have a large MySQL 5.5 database in which many rows are inserted daily and never deleted or updated. There are also users querying the live database. Tables are MyISAM.
But it is effectively impossible to run ANALYZE TABLES because it takes way too long. And so the query optimizer will often pick the wrong index. (15 hours, and sometimes crashes the tables.)

We want to try switching to all InnoDB. Will we need to run ANALYZE TABLES or not?

The MySQL docs say: 
The cardinality (the number of different key values) in every index of a table
is calculated when a table is opened, at SHOW TABLE STATUS and ANALYZE TABLE and
on other circumstances (like when the table has changed too much).

But that begs the question: when is a table opened? If that means accessed during a connection then we need do nothing special. But I do not think that that is the case for InnoDB.

So what is the best approach? Run ANALYZE TABLE periodically? Perhaps with an increased dive count?

Or will it all happen automatically?

The query users use apps to get the data, so each run is a separate connection. They generally do NOT expect the rows to be up-to-date within just minutes.